# ドメイン駆動設計のエンティティにgetterは必須でしょうか

Tags: ドメイン駆動設計

DDDでエンティティをORM（例えばPHPのLaravel（Eloquent））を利用して永続化する際、リポジトリの実装の中でエンティティをORM固有のオブジェクトに詰め替える必要があるように思うのですが、つまりエンティティにはgetterが必須ということになるのでしょうか？

```
function persist($itemEntity) {
    $item = new Item(); // ORMのオブジェクト

    $item->id = $itemEntity->getId()->value();
    $item->name = $itemEntity->getName()->value();

    $item->save();
}
```

PHPでDDDの実装サンプルを見ると皆このようになっています。
が、IDDD本のサンプルコードを見る限り永続化メソッドにgetterは登場していないように見えます。（但しJavaはよく分かっていないのでコードの意味が理解出来ていないだけかもしれません。）

Viewに渡すようなクエリ系はCQSのクエリサービス+DTOの構造にして、getterの役割はDTO側に実装しつつ、コマンド側に徹するエンティティからはgetterを取り除いてより閉じた状態にしたいと考えたのですが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getterは必須ではありません。
ちょっと手間ですが、私は「リポジトリでカプセル化を破るためのインタフェース」を使うことがよくあります。
※多分何かのデザインパターンとして名前があったと思いますが、分からないです

PHPが分からないのでJavaで書きます。

```
// Hogeエンティティ
// ドメインモデルなので当然ドメインレイヤーに配置
public class Hoge {
    // IDはずっと変化しない
    // ドメイン上ではgetterが不要だが、永続化の際に取り出せる必要がある
    private final int id;

    // 名前は変更することがある
    private String name;

    public Hoge(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void rename(String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public void deencapsulate(HogeDeencapsulator deencap) {
        deencap.setId(this.id);
        deencap.setName(this.name);
    }
}

// Hogeのカプセル化を破るためのインタフェース
// これはドメインレイヤーに配置
public interface HogeDeencapsulator {
    void setId();
    void setName();
}

// HogeDeencapsulatorの実装クラス
// これはリポジトリの実装と同じインフラレイヤーに配置
public class HogeDeencapsulatorImpl implements HogeDeencapsulator{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ここまで用意すれば、リポジトリの実装では次のようにしてHogeのidを取り出せます。

```
public void save(Hoge hoge) {
    HogeDeencapsulatorImpl hogeDeencap = new HogeDeencapsulatorImpl();
    hoge.deencapsulate(hogeDeencap);

    int id = hogeDeencap.getId();
    String name = hogeDeencap.getName();
    ...
}
```

どうしてもカプセル化を維持したい場合に使ってます。
列挙型（enum）を持ってるけど、ドメインとしてのインタフェースは「isなんちゃら」のメソッドしか公開したくない場合とかも。
面倒なときは普通にgetter付けちゃいますが。

Comment: ご丁寧な説明本当にありがとうございます！こういう実践的な内容は非常に勉強になります。

getterは必須ではないものの、取り除くには一手間必要なので「どうしてもカプセル化を維持したい場合に」という感じなのですね。
僕の場合今回「なんとなくカプセル化したい」程度なので過設計に陥りそうだなと判断できました。

事の発端はコマンド系とクエリ系を分離させてみようと思ったところなんですが、CQS自体も過剰な気がしてきたので、シンプルにgetterを付けたEntityで全てまかなってしまおうかなと思っています。